# upload image with parameters, using angular-file-upload, carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, file-upload, carrierwave, multipartform-data

plz help me with this:
i'm using this directive [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) to upload single image with parameters:

```
uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader(
      url: '/recipes',
      alias:  'cover',
      removeAfterUpload:  true,
      #transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token,'accept': 'application/json'},
      withCredentials: true
    )


uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item)->
          #data = angular.toJSON($scope.recipe)
          item.formData.push("recipe": angular.toJson($scope.recipe))
          #item.upload()
          console.info('uploader', $scope.uploader);
          uploader.uploadAll()
```

this is the create action:

```
def create

        @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:instructions))
        @recipe.user_id = current_user.id
        @recipe.save
        render 'show', status: 201
      end
```

this is the request:

```
Started POST "/recipes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-06 20:29:20 +0100
Processing by RecipesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"recipe"=>"{\"name\":\"cnfsl*k\",\"instructions\":\"mcdmùdsd\",\"ingredients\":[{\"id\":4,\"title\":\"sucre\"}]}", "cover"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb42de9e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151206-5852-txz5ls.jpg>, @original_filename="6.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cover\"; filename=\"6.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
```

i got an error

```
undefined method `permit' for #<String:0xb40a6270>
```

can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `params[:recipe]` is not a `hash` but a `json`. You need to parse it first. Try to add this line as the first line in your `create` action:

```
params[:recipe] = JSON.parse params[:recipe]
```

Comment: i got this Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in Recipes#create 
"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8